# ImmutableJS and Redux Observable with RXJS 6.x

Tags: redux, rxjs, immutable.js, redux-observable, rxjs6

I have an existing project that uses ImmutableJS for state, Redux Observable middleware, and RXJS 5.x. I noticed that latest version of Redux Observable that uses RXJS 6.x has a different dependency injection pattern than before. Specifically, that the store injection has been replaced with "state$" stream. My question is can I use RXJS 6.x with ImmutableJS? Would I treat "state$" as a normal immmutable object and use things like "state$.get('username')"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the state by calling `store.getState()` anymore. Instead, you subscribe to the `state$` stream to receive the changes as they occur. The events emitted will simply be the value that you would've obtained by calling `store.getState()`. If that was an ImmutableJS object, then that's what you'll get. The change means very little in the context of using ImmutableJS objects versus standard objects.

There are multiple ways to leverage the new `state$` stream, and specifics on how to accomplish something will depend on your use cases. The really neat thing about the `state$` stream is that epics can react to state changes without necessarily having an action to kick things off.

Let's say you want to get/use the latest version of the state when an action occurs. You can simply use the `withLatestFrom` operator:

```js
const epic = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(ACTION_TYPE),
  withLatestFrom(state$),
  mergeMap(([action, state]) => ...),
)
```

This is more or less the replacement for `store.getState()`. For each matching action, the current state at that moment in time will be passed along. The next operator after `withLatestFrom` will receive an array (or a "tuple") with the action that occurred at index 0 and the current state at index 1.

Building on this, you may want to use the `state$` observable multiple times when implementing a larger workflow:

```js
const epic = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(LOAD_PROFILE),
  withLatestFrom(state$),
  switchMap(([action, state]) =>
    concat(
      merge(
        state.get('profile') === undefined
          ? ajax.getJSON(...).pipe(...) // emit some action(s)
          : empty(),
        state.get('friendList') === undefined
          ? ajax.getJSON(...).pipe(...) // emit some action(s)
          : empty(),
      ),
      state$.pipe( // get a fresh, updated copy of state
        first(),
        map(state => [state, state.get('profile')]),
        filter(([state, profile]) => profile.get('hasStars') && state.get('stars') === undefined),
        mergeMap(() => ajax.getJSON(...).pipe(...)), // emit some action(s)
      ),
    )
  ),
)
```